# Azure data lake - is it possible to download and execute a successful job in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-data-lake

Visual studio allows you to download and debug failed jobs from the azure datalake. (jobs > select job name > "Download" (in the yellow bar)).

I want to analyse the behaviour of my compiled data lake assembly in visual studio.

Is it possible to debug a successful job in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to the failed vertex debug function that lets you take a portion of a failed job (a single vertex) and download the code and data for local debug. That is not currently available for successful portions of a job.

However, you can run an entire script locally on your dev box with the VS debug or run without debug commands. This will let you put breakpoints in your user code (.NET code). You may have to create a smaller dataset for your local test.